# Node.js script suddenly stops on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My node.js script runs fine when I run it from the command line. But when I create deployment and run script in Google Cloud Function, it executed only partially. Script stops working in different parts of the code, for example when I make http-request, or when use Jimp library, or when download file from firebase storage. Nothing errors or notification messages about it. When run it from command line at computer all good.
Part of the source code:

```
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
        // Download file from bucket.
        console.log("load file font png");
        return bucket.file(filenameFontPng).download({destination: tempLocalFileFontPng});
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("load file font fnt");
        return bucket.file(filenameFontFnt).download({destination: tempLocalFileFontFnt});
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("all files downloaded");

        Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(function (font) { 
            console.log("load font 1");
            font_white = font;
            return font_white;
        }).then(() => {
            Jimp.loadFont(tempLocalFileFontFnt).then(function (font) { 
                console.log("load font 2");
                font_yellow = font;
                return font_yellow;
            }).then(() => {
                load_images(0);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return Jimp.loadFont(...)`? You might be missing some `return` statements.

Comment: @JamesLawson No, because loadFont working fine, but after load_images(0) it has stopped. Or if first load images and than load font, it will be stopped at moment when I try to load font, or if it will be http request, it will be stopped at this moment